# How to hide (disable) journal in OpenERP 6

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to hide some unused journals. It seems in older versions, journals had an `active` attribute which allowed to hide them from views (like "products" for example).

I can't find any similar option in OpenERP 6.0.

How can I hide or disable some Journals so they don't appear normally in journal listings?

Comment: Journal items? Journal entries? You can always hide them yourself by creating a new module and using inheritance

Comment: I think I just mean Journals (`account_journal` type). Regarding customizing this, I was asking if I can do this with an out-of-the-box system, as this was working in previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that field was removed in 6.0 for some reason. You can either create a bug report / feature request to have it put back, or write your own custom module that adds (via python) and displays (via XML) that field on the Journal configuration screen.